# WSO2 ESB requirement to pass xml as a Soap Attachment

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We have a requirement to pass xml as a Soap Attachment in soap request. At present we are handling this requirement in a custom class mediator; we are trying to achieve this requirement through WSO2 ESB inbuilt mediators without coding the functionality in a custom class mediator. We are exploring for this option on WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 and 4.8.0
Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Soap request with attachment is as shown below. Xml file is attached is passed in the custom class mediator.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:swa="http://aasws.com/swa">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <swa:OurHeader>
         <swa:Credential>
            <swa:Username>XXXX</swa:Username>
            <swa:Password>XXXX</swa:Password>
            <swa:Dbtitle>XXXX</swa:Dbtitle>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <swa:Domain/>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <swa:Accessuser/>
         </swa:Credential>
      </swa:OurHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <swa:getServiceInfo>
         <swa:attachmentID>XXXX.xml</swa:attachmentID>
      </swa:getServiceInfo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please see the below question

Answer (score 0):

You can send a SOAP attachment in WSO2 ESB via MTOM. Please find the following links which explain in detail how you can achieve this task.

[1] http://hi-my-world.blogspot.com/2015/01/sending-attachements-with-with-esb-via.html

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33136025

[3] http://wso2.com/library/1148/

Cheers,
Pubudu.